# cant boot into windows after dual booting elementary OS hera

Tags: dual-boot, microsoft-windows, release-hera

I am new to linux and decided to check out elementary OS,I carried out a dual boot by shrinking my hard drive,deleted one of my recovery partition(100mb) and creating an extended partition where I installed elementary OS. while installing I chose the manual created a swap partition an an ext4 partition.

After the installation, I was able to boot elementary OS, but when I try to boot windows 10 from grub, I get a black screen and then it goes back to grub.

i have tried updating grub, and some other fixes i saw here but none has worked so far. i tired boot repair and got this  http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CsGGzVsPnn/  . i rally need help with this.

PS  i tried installing a new version of windows but it keeps crashing. before i get to the install page

Comment: To be sure, have you got 2 disk, i see `SDA` and `SDB` and for me you have no root for your linux

Comment: its 1 hard drive with 4 partitions.

Comment: Normally `sda` is the first disk and `sdb` is the second

Comment: when i carried out boot repair, a live usb was connected to my pc, that was probably the reason for sdb. here i ran it again without the usb connected.. http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PhRRFYw7d7/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because you have deleted the windows recovery partition. I have similar experience by deleting windows recovery partition on another computer.

**I do not pretend that this is the best approach** but if I am in a situation like yours I will proceed like this:

1. boot into elementary os
2. backup all Windows data I want to save, install Gparted if it is not installed yet and remove all ntfs and *fat partitions. Create a new NTFS one.
3. backup all data I want to save from elementary OS because usually installing windows destroys the Linux installations.
4. Install Windows
5. Install elementary OS. It is possible just to repair the elementary OS installation with some recovery cd, but if you do not have so much things to save (you said that it is not and old installation with a lot of programs and services installed) you better wipe it and reinstall it from sctratch.

*// the **boot/efi** is in a vfat partition, probably it is possible to save elementary OS if you keep this partition, but based on my experience windows will overwrite it and usually it will contain a lot of bulk data. There is also an option to save the efi bootloader information from there somewhere and after installing windows to restore it, but I never succeeded doing like this. I don't say it is impossible, but again, **if I am in your situation** I will make everything from sctratch.